# SANE not detecting scanner by ID (pipe error) or path (invalid arg)

Tags: usb, scanner, sane

I have a Canon P-208II, which uses the `canon_dr` backend [0].

However, I noticed from `lsusb` that the product ID of mine (`0x1660`) differs from that in `/etc/sane.d/canon_dr.conf` and `/usr/lib/udev/rules/49-sane.rules` (`0x165f`), so I duplicated those lines, modifying the ID to match.

```
$ lsusb
[...]
Bus 001 Device 017: ID 1083:1660 Canon Electronics, Inc. CANON   P-208II
[...]
```

Despite that, neither `sane-find-scanner` nor `scanimage -L` detect the scanner, with verbose logging I can see it trying to access and getting permissions errors, or with root:

```
could not fetch string descriptor: Pipe error
```

in the same location.

I also tried `sane-find-scanner /dev/usb/001/017`, which says `failed to open (Invalid argument)` - I'm not sure what else to give as 'devname' [1]?

Is there somewhere else I need to change the product ID, or something to do to make the changes I have made take effect? Or is the pipe error a smoking gun?

---

[0] - http://www.sane-project.org/sane-mfgs.html

[1] - http://www.sane-project.org/man/sane-find-scanner.1.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahah! Thanks to a 2015 hint from M. Allan Noah [0], I found that the reported product ID changes according to the postition of the 'auto start' switch on the back of the scanner:

```
Off - 0x165f
On - 0x1660
```

(it is necessary to re-plug after toggling the switch)

In the 'off' position, it thus reports the ID SANE was expecting, and works with nothing further - that 'pipe error' is unrelated and still occurs.

Works out of the box! ... as long as it comes out in the correct state.

[0] - http://sane.10972.n7.nabble.com/cannon-p208-raspberian-tp20448p20457.html